# Azure DevOps Organization Setting

Tags: azure

There are multiple organizations listed when I go to our Azure DevOps. I own one of the orgs and manage all projects for the company there. I would like to move my Organization to the top of my orgs list. Can you suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, this functionality is not available.  Please help us improve Azure DevOps by requesting this as a new feature.

https://aka.ms/AzureDevOpsSuggestions